# ear in multimodule: Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.4

Tags: eclipse, maven, ear

I have a multi-module maven project. When I import it into eclipse helios I get the correct JRE 1.6 for war and ejb modules. But the default 1.4 for ear-modules.

The following is specified in the root pom

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>          
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

What do I need to add to get 1.6 for ear-modules?

(This is a variation on [Warning - Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138384/java-warning-build-path-specifies-execution-environment-j2se-1-4) which has the correct solution for other than ear-packaging.)

Comment: Do you have at least 1.0 version of m2e and m2e-wtp?

Comment: No, had m2e 0.12. Got problems after installing newest m2e though. Currently upgrading to indigo to see if that solves my problems. Will update here when done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update

- m2e (Maven Integration for Eclipse) to at least 1.0.2
- m2e-wtp (Maven Integration for WTP) to at least 0.15.2

(as Michal Kalinowski points out above.)