# Error in eclipse: “The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved”

Tags: eclipse

My eclipse project shows up but with a red exclamation mark and an error saying:

1. Build path specifies execution envoirnment JRE-1.1. There are no compatible JREs installed in the workspace
2. Unbound classpath container : 'JRE System Library [JRE -1.1]' in project Automation

I checked if all the libraries are present or not as mentioned in the error, and tried to import the missing jar into project but when I clicked on JRE System Library [JRE -1.1] to import it. its showing

"An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
java.lang.NullPointerException"

Can somebody help me out with this?

Comment: You may want to try the steps mentioned in the below thread
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138384/java-warning-build-path-specifies-execution-environment-j2se-1-4

Comment: I tried this but when I select JRE System Library [JRE -1.1] to import its giving NullPointerException. So its not working!

Comment: Stack trace?  Have you reported the bug to http://bugs.eclipse.org ?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand. I have not reported this bug to eclipse.org. Am I suppose to do that?

Comment: When you encounter an Exception? Yes.

Comment: Excuse me - do you use Java version 1 ???!!!

Comment: How come the answer you 'accepted' solves your problem??? It's a QUESTION, not an answer...

Comment: Sorry.. I wanted to choose the other one, choose this one by mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was getting the same NullPointerException in Eclipse that came with Android SDK, then I did the following (explaining in step by step process):

1. Go to Help and click on Install New Softwares.
2. A Install window will open, click on "All available sites' and then there will be a text box to search for the softwares you want to install, enter 'Eclipse' there.
3. A lots of Eclipse related softwares will come up. Select Eclipse Platform, Eclipse Platform SDK and Eclipse SDK and then click Next...Next...(and all the Next)...Accept All the Agreements...Finish.
4. In some time it will install all the softwares and you'll have to restart the eclipse and you'll be good to go.

This resolved my issue. Hope this helps you.