# "There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment."

Tags: java, eclipse

I just downloaded the "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" and I opened it up, started it up and got the error "Build path specifies execution environment CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.". I have no idea what this mean, as I'm still trying to wrap my had around all this java stuff. I look at my installations and I see this:

- Java 7 Update 60
- Java 8 Update 5 (64-bit)
- Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 5 (64-bit)

Please help, I have no idea what I'm doing or what to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138384/java-warning-build-path-specifies-execution-environment-j2se-1-4

Comment: @bbalchev Did not help, still confused.

Comment: When you do `New > Java Project` what values do you have in the JRE section of the first page of the wizard? You should be able to select a JavaSE-1.xxx environment.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry! Everybody was new at some point. I remember when I was starting out and I felt like a noob too :P. I'm sorry, but it is hard for me to figure out exactly what your problem is, but I think a smart idea is to make sure you are downloading Eclipse from the correct place.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Is where I suggest you download Eclipse. If I remember correctly, once you start to download it, the website will guide you through whatever you need to go through to download Java. All I can currently recommend is that you download the newest version. From my experience, for whatever reason, I already had Java on my system. Another thing that might help is when you download the IDE, download the package (which at this time is named the Kepler Package) instead of just the IDE. I hope that helped. Happy programming!

Comment: Yeah, i'm downloading it from there, and I think i'm downloading the package "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers". My problem is is whenever I create a new project in Eclipse, inside the problems box I get "build path specifies execution environment CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment." I have no idea what that means and I tried googling it, but no results helped :(.

Comment: Hmmm. I hope you don't mind me throwing suggestions at you, because I think I'm ever so slightly less clueless than you are :(. Did you also try updating/downloading a newer version of Java from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnjp

Comment: Oh, I just found a great tutorial series. Since you're new to Java, I think this would be a great series for you. It will show you how to download everything you need and teach you about programming in Java. If you are unable to figure out how to download it, you should follow video series. From what I've seen, it's very good! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hl-zzrqQoSE&list=PLFE2CE09D83EE3E28

Answer (score 0):

To use Java applications such as Java games on the internet you need Java JRE (Java Runtime Environment). But for developing Java applications you need Java JDK too (Java Development Kit).
Sometimes Eclipse is not very specific with the exceptions and errors and although it's telling you abount JRE, maybe the problem is that you don't have JDK installed.

You shoul select a JDK installation in Eclipse to work. 
Go to Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs. There you should see a list of the JREs and JDKs installed (if you have different versions). Select the lastest version of a JDK and save changes.