# Eclipse: no JREs installed in the workspace strictly compatible with the environment

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, maven

I created a **Maven** project by using **Eclipse Kepler** as IDE.

I configure the `pom.xml` properties as follows:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>
```

I'm using the **JDK 1.8** on **Mac OS X 10.9.4 Maverics**: this version may support also the previous **1.7**, as shown below:

[image: Build path]

Despite that, Eclipse gives me a warning:

```
Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-1.7. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.
```

Usually this warning could be resolved as described **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138384/java-warning-build-path-specifies-execution-environment-j2se-1-4)**, but in this case the procedure doesn't work (because the JRE 1.7 is already selected).

Perhaps, I should also install on my system a *pure* version of JDK 1.7, but the installer returns me an error as follows:

[image: JDK Installer]

Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Go and check the `Java compiler` settings of your project (right click, `Properties`). This could be a problem of level of compliance.

Comment: Also the Java compiler is set to work with `Java 1.7`.

Comment: The only way would be to force an install of 7. The "strict" issue is because the Java 8 installation contains new APIs that are source-compatible with 7 but won't be present in a Java 7 JRE.