# How do I update the Maven configuration in Eclipse Luna?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am using Java 8 for my JRE in Eclipse Luna with with the m2e Maven plugin. I see this warning as soon as I create a Maven project: `Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.5. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.` I see lots of older advice on this site on how to deal with this error, but nothing related to Java 8. I also that [Oracle says J2SE was deprecated in 2008](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/index-jsp-138567.html). The most promising answer I have found thus far comes from @Pascal Thivent here:

[Warning - Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138384/warning-build-path-specifies-execution-environment-j2se-1-4)

But these instructions no longer seem to be relevant for Luna:

> Eclipse project Properties > Maven > Update Project Configuration

I only see "Lifecycle mapping" under Maven.

[image]

Can someone please explain (1) what this error means (2) if it is still a worry, given that J2SE-1.5 seems to have been deprecated (3) how to best fix it in Luna?

Comment: I think you should update the POM first and then the m2e configuration for that project. (Probably something like this for Maven: http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireJavaVersion.html)

Comment: Its because you don't a JRE 5 installed in Eclipse: `Prefereces > Java > Installed JREs`

Comment: `Update Project Configuration` is in context menu of project in project panel under `maven` menu

Comment: change your installed jre to point to JDK 1.5

Comment: @JigarJoshi but I need JRE 8 for some of the jars in my project

Comment: ok then change your pom.xml to have compiler plugin to use 1.8 as source and target and change your installed JRE to point to JDk 1.8

Comment: @JigarJoshi is this what I need to set in my pom.xml? http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This error is because the project pom file is instructing maven to compile against java 1.5.
2. It is best to compile and test to a current java version. In your case java 8.
3. I am unsure how to fix it inside the eclipse IDE, but the project pom file can be edited to include the compile version as follows:

   ```
   <plugin>  
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>    
     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>    
     <version>3.1</version>    
     <configuration>    
       <source>1.8</source>    
       <target>1.8</target>    
     </configuration>    
   </plugin>
   ```