# Jaspersoft Studio 6.2 Build Path Warning

Tags: java, linux, jasperserver, jaspersoft-studio

I've recently installed Jasperserver and Jaspersoft Studio to work with JasperReports. After creating a database connection to my PostgreSQL database and building a report from that database, I'm getting the following warning in Jaspersoft Studio, which I've been unable to resolve.

```
Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-1.6. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.
```

I found the configuration didn't have an associated JRE System Library, so I tried using the JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.6] installed with Jaspersoft Studio, which does not resolve the problem. I have also tried to use jre.linux.gtk.x86_64.feature_1.8.0.u65, and CDC-1.0/Foundation-1.0(jre.linux.gtk.x86_64.feature_1.8.0.u65) without success.

This must be a configuration issue, but I've been unable to locate a resource on the web to resolve the configuration problem.

Comment: I think you have two different problems the JRE error is a classpath error this is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138384/warning-build-path-specifies-execution-environment-j2se-1-4.

Comment: The problem of not viewing table is probably related to your datasource expression... you need to include some relevant jrxml.

Comment: When using the table component use the HTML format rather than Java to view the data. This can be selected in the Preview tab.

Comment: @Petter Friberg I saw that post prior to posting, and that's exactly what I did without success. I'm new to this, but I see no issues with the reports .jrxml creation. Regardless of the format, the report is not displaying.

Comment: Lets concentrate on the table problem..., the rest of your report is generate except a table component in some band?, pass the relevant jrxml of the table component at its subDataset (edit the post)

Comment: Also try to log everything when you compile and fill the report (a nice try catch (Throwable ex ){ex.printStackTrace()}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are new to the Eclipes environment and to Jaspersoft Studio, this complete answer will help you achieve success in removing the warning.

1. With the project active in the Design view, select *Project* from the main menu bar and the *Properties* option at the bottom of the dropdown. If your project is not active, Properties will be disabled. To activate the Properties option, select the Design view near the lower one third of the IDE page in the middle pane, then click inside the page area of your design view. Not *Properties* in the *Project* menu should be active.
2. In the far left panel of the dialog, select the "Java Build Path" from the available options.
3. **Add Library** from the buttons in the far right of the dialog.
4. Select "JRE System Library" from the options, and the **Next >** button.
5. Select the "Execution environment:" radio option, which should automatically populate the JRE System Library available. If it doesn't, try using the "Alternate JRE:". All of this step assumes that you have a JRE installed on your system, which is not the default library installed by Jaspersoft Studio.
6. Select the **Finish** button.
7. This step is important, because if you don't remove the library installed in your project by default, the warning will not disappear. Select JRE System Library[J2SE 1.6] from the middle section labeled "JARs and class folders on the build path:", select the **Remove** button on the right.
8. Select the **Apply** button, then the **OK** button.

At this point, clean your project and rebuild it. The warning should be gone.

Even though this answer is specific to Jaspersoft Studio, and the JRE System Library[J2SE 1.6], you may be able to extrapolate this solution to other platforms, but this assumes the interface has not significantly changed.

Comment: This can be extrapolated for Jaspersoft Studio 6.6.0: 
Properties->Java Build Path->Order and Export->JRE System Library->Apply and Close->Clean/Build