# Error: Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-10. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible.

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, java-11

I'm having issues with setting up the JREs in my VSCode workspace. I thought the issue was correctly setting up my `java.home` in my `settings.json` but I'm still getting this error:

`Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-10. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible.`

I've looked at the answer here ([Warning - Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138384/warning-build-path-specifies-execution-environment-j2se-1-4)) but the solution is for Eclipse and not VSCode.

I think it is because the JRE is specifying Java10 and I'm using Java11.

Any suggestions on how to set up the JRE for VSCode?

Also, here is the java version I'm using and my settings.

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V

Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
    11.0.1, x86_64: "Java SE 11.0.1"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

And my `java.home` settings in VSCode:

`"java.home": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home"`

Comment: I am not very sure of what VScode is looking for, but there is no JRE since in Java11. It's just the JDK.

Comment: If you're using Maven, have you tried adding `<source>11</source> <target>11</target>` to your POM?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I'll try that! Thanks

Comment: I also have this problem. I am working with legacy code, I have set source and target to 8. and installed the jre/sdk with sdkman.io, what should I configure?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException it will be great if you add the above comment as an answer and request the seeker to mark that as answer if the response is satisfactory to him/her. In this way the solution to this problem will be searchable as well ! Just a note the referenced comment helped me though.

Comment: Your command `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` helped me find my jdk location when I had this same problem. I didn't have the /Contents/Home included in my setting. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I have setup Maven as the build environment for Java within VSCode. For maven, I found that one of the build properties in pom.xml was set to Java version 1.8, which was older than what I was using, namely 1.11. Once I updated the property as below, the warning disappeared.

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.11</java.version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 7):

To totally remove the warnings/errors, I believe you need to:

- ensure that JDK 10 is installed
- as per [limitations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_jdk-for-projects), use "`JavaSE-10`" as the `name` in the `java.configuration.runtimes` array in your `settings.json`

Given the question was posed in 2018, for my current version of VS Code (1.49.2), it will use a higher JDK version in "compatibility" mode and similar messages are [just warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifqlN.png).

As I had some difficulty myself figuring out and configuring everything, and this still ranks high on Google searches, I am documenting the full instructions for setting the `java.configuration.runtimes` (particularly in regards to Windows *and* WSL), since it is preferable for me to not change the entire default JDK using the `java.home` setting (particularly since this might break JSL also if using JDK versions < 11, as explained below).

According to:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_configure-jdk:

  - the Java Language Server requires Java SE 11 or later
- https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java#setting-the-jdk

  - the `java.home` setting should be used to point to the JDK used by the JLS, and also code compilation if not explicitly overridden
  - there is a *precedence* for the variables referenced, i.e.:

    - the `java.home` setting in VS Code settings (*workspace* then *user* settings)
    - the `JDK_HOME` environment variable
    - the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable
    - on the current system path
  - to compile against a different JDK, set the `java.configuration.runtimes` in the respective `settings.json` (i.e. workspace and/or user):

    ```
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
      {
        "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
        "path": "/path/to/jdk-8",
      },
      {
        "name": "JavaSE-11",
        "path": "/path/to/jdk-11",
      },
      {
        "name": "JavaSE-14",
        "path": "/path/to/jdk-14",
        "default": true
      },
      {
        "name": "JavaSE-15",
        "path": "/path/to/jdk-15",
        "default": true
      },
    ]
    ```
  - **NOTE**: I am unsure why the example has *two* `default`s, but the example from their own [Wiki](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/JDK-Requirements#setting-the-jdk) and the [VS marketplace description](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java#setting-the-jdk) have only one.

To edit the `settings.json` to add (or edit) the `java.configuration.runtimes` setting/s:

1. press CTRL+, (comma)
2. choose the correct "heading"/`settings.json` you are attempting to edit (i.e. *user* or specific *workspace/s*) ([screenshot showing 3 environments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okXVy.png))
3. type "`java.configuration.runtimes`" in the search box
4. if "No Settings Found" is returned, edit the `settings.json` file directly by clicking on the `Open Settings (JSON)' button near the top right of the window
   (as per above screenshot)
5. edit the appropriate `settings.json` and enter your customised `java.configuration.runtimes` snippet (as exemplified above), ensuring to use only the allowed "`name`"s (as mentioned above) and using the correct paths (taking into account if it is Windows or Linux paths - the latter applicable to WSL)
6. close the `settings.json` edit window
7. set your Maven `pom.xml`'s `maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.target`, synchronising the project's Java classpath and configuration [when prompted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kM7Bf.png) (which will also update your Eclipse `org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs`' `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform`, `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance` and `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source` accordingly (if it also exists)

Example `java.configuration.runtimes` snippet from `settings.json`:

- Windows (JDK 1.8 and 12 installed)

  ```
  "java.configuration.runtimes": [
      {
          "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
          "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_261"
      },
      {
          "name": "JavaSE-12",
          "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-12.0.1"
      }
  ]
  ```
- WSL (remote) (JDK 1.8 and 11 installed):

  ```
  "java.configuration.runtimes": [
      {
          "name:": "JavaSE-1.11",
          "path": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
      },
      {
          "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
          "path": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
      }
  ]
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I just changed:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

To:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

1.7 -> 1.8

Where 1.8 is my java version

In your terminal:

```
java -version
```

I will get:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_292-8u292-b10-0ubuntu1~20.04-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)
```

I'm using java `1.8` so it must be `1.8`

If you are using `1.11` so it must be `1.11` and so on...